# js задача на перестановку элементов масива

Tags: javascript

Вот задача:

Дано четырехзначное число.
Переставьте местами цифры так, чтобы сначала оказались цифры, меньшие пяти.

```
let arr = [1, 7, 23, 3];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < 5) {
        arr.push(arr.splice(1, 2));
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Написано "четырехначаное число", вижу массив с 4 числами... в чем подвох?!)

Answer (score 2):

Можно работать со строкой:

```js
let num = String(9481);

let x = Array.prototype.concat( num.match(/[0-4]/g), num.match(/[5-9]/g) ).join("");
                         // [...num.match(/[0-4]/g), ...num.match(/[5-9]/g)]

console.log( +x ); // Плюсик превращает строку в число.
```

Метод `match()` ищет совпадение в строке и возвращает массив найденных совпадений. В качестве аргумента можно передать просто строку, но чаще всего используется регулярное выражение. Как кавычки для строк... так и символ `/` является "кавычкой" для регулярного выражения.

`[0-4]` означает одно совпадение из отрезка 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Но если написать `/[0-4]/` — оно просто найдет и вернет одно число. А флажок `g` (general) - говорит "найди все совпадения в строке".

Подробнее → http://learn.javascript.ru/ (3-я часть, 'регулярные выражения')

В итоге первое выражение возвращает массив [4, 1] а второе [9, 8]. Они склеиваются и собираются в строку `.join("")` — на выходе получается 4198.

---

А если очень хочется разбить в массив...

```js
let num = ("" + 9481).split("")
let temp = [];

for( let i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ){
  temp[ (num[i] < 5) ? "unshift" : "push" ]( num[i] );
}

console.log( +temp.join("") );
```

Тут проверяется условие... если оно верное, значение будет unshift, иначе - push. Все числа меньше 5 добавляются вначале, а остальные - в конце.

Comment: СПС большое , но в строке где let x = Array.prototype.concat( num.match(/[0-4]/g), num.match(/[5-9]/g) ).join(""); что происходит в [таких скобках] и что значит / и /g

Comment: @cocojambo1 Добавил подробности.